# Kotlin get first character from list of strings

Tags: kotlin

I have a kotlin list of strings. I need the first characters of each string in the list and format the string the below expected way. Is there a buitin method equivalent to get first characters in the list?

```
fun main() {
    val stringlist = listOf("One", "Two", "Four")
    var name = "Flock"
    // Current Output Flock:One:Two:Four
    println(name + ":"+ stringlist.joinToString(":"))
    // expected output Flock:O:T:F
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extract the first character with *map* from the list:

```
fun main() {
  val firstCharList = listOf("One", "Two", "Four").map { it.first() }
  val name = "Flock"
  println(name + ":" + firstCharList.joinToString(":"))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also pass `it.take(1)` to the `transform` parameter of `joinToString`. `take(n)` returns the first `n` characters of the string. You don't need to handle any error or nullability here as `take(n)` returns the original string if `n` is greater than length of string.

```kotlin
println(name + ":"+ stringlist.joinToString(":") { it.take(1) })
```

[Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/pQ1o5dRQC)

Answer (score 2):

The last parameter of `joinToString` is a lambda of type `(T) -> CharSequence` where you can transform each element into the CharSequence that should appear in the output. So your code would become:

```
println(name + ":" + stringlist.joinToString(":") { it.first().toString() })
```

Note that `first` would throw in case the string is empty. If you want to avoid that you can filter out empty strings beforehand or use something like `firstOrNull()?.toString().orEmpty()` to transform empty strings into empty strings.